# Accepted shared outlook.com calendar now what

Tags: calendar, windows-live, outlook.com

I've shared my live.com calendar with another outlook.com account following the steps at [Share with People You Choose](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/outlook/calendar-share).  I clicked on the accept link in the the outlook.com account.  It asks me to log in, but I just see the calendar for the outlook.com account.  I don't see a way to see the calendar that I've supposedly shared.  Does anyone know how to get this to work?  I've shared calendars via urls before, but this sounds like it would be better if I could get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this "sharing with people" will show you open times and relevant information to them (share receiver), when you attempt to create & send an appointment/ meeting invite from the other account (share receiver).

A - Share Calendar
B - Receive Shared Calendar
B - Creates & Sends Appt. / Meeting Request - while doing this can see their own calendar and the open/ close times of A's calendar

I do not know for sure as I have not done this with anyone on live.com/ outlook.com personal accounts.

But, the typical behavior in Corporate Exchange Outlook is one where all employees are able to see 'partial' schedules i.e. atleast open/ close parts of other peoples calendars, when they wish to send an appointment/ meeting invite.